# Jquery UI sortable with table

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

Consider the following image.

[image]

In the following image, rows are divided as a section of few rows.
I have implemented the Jquery UI sortable with the table but by that, any row can be inserted anywhere in the table.

What I want is, rows can only be sortable within their specific section, for example, a row of one section should not insert in section 2.

So I'm looking for something like validation on jumping say, a row cannot jump another row with a specific class or let me know something else.

Below is the piece of code for jquery.

```
$(function(){
            $("#etemplate_table_id").sortable({   /*etemplate_table_id - table id*/
                items:".tbl_row_4",          /*tbl_row_4 - class of rows in yellow color*/
                cursor:"move"
            });
        });
```

Below is code to produce sample html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css">
</head>
<body>


        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered tbl_style " id="etemplate_table_id">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="tbl_row_head" "="">
                        <th>M</th>
                        <th>W</th>
                        <th>A</th>
                        <th>Detailed Description</th>
                        <th>R-Class</th>
                        <th>B-Class</th>
                        <th>E-Category</th>
                        <th>ML-Category</th>
                        <th>Labor Rate</th>
                        <th>QTY</th>
                        <th>UOM</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Crew Size</th>
                        <th>Unit Mhrs.</th>
                        <th>Total Mhrs.</th>
                        <th>Phase</th>
                        <th>Total Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <tr class="tbl_row_1" id="H0111">
                                        <td>01</td>
                                        <td colspan="8" class="left_align">House # 109, Vienna Andre</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr><tr class="tbl_row_2" id="01_01-tbl_row_2" name="W002">
                                        <td>01.01</td>
                                        <td colspan="8" class="left_align wbs_master_list_td">Head &amp; Trauma Pt</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>16</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="tbl_row_3">
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td class="cell_grp_brown">Test</td>
                                        <td colspan="7" class="left_align">Activity Description</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>16</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr><tr class="tbl_row_4 no_wrap_class" id="H0111__W002__1066">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td class="cell_grp_brown">01.01.03</td>
                                            <td>1066</td>
                                            <td class="no_wrap_class">Develop Tower Near Yellow East River</td>
                                            <td>DATA1</td>
                                            <td>OM_CL</td>
                                            <td>110100</td>
                                            <td>Contractor</td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td><input size="1" value="" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>LS</td>
                                            <td class="duration_cell">9 days</td>
                                            <td class="crew_cell"><select class="crew_dropdown"><option selected="">0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input value="8" size="1" class="unit_mhrs_input" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td>2</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="tbl_row_4 no_wrap_class" id="H0111__W002__1259">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td class="cell_grp_brown">01.01.04</td>
                                            <td>1259</td>
                                            <td class="no_wrap_class">Install Marron Wire M001</td>
                                            <td>PCC-1</td>
                                            <td>ME_CL</td>
                                            <td>130100</td>
                                            <td>Testing &amp; Commissioning</td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td><input size="1" value="" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>Days</td>
                                            <td class="duration_cell">5 days</td>
                                            <td class="crew_cell"><select class="crew_dropdown"></select></td>
                                            <td><input value="8" size="1" class="unit_mhrs_input" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td>3</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="tbl_row_10" id="01_01-tbl_row_10">
                                        <td colspan="12" class="right_align">Subtotal For Head &amp; Trauma Pt</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>16</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>$0</td>
                                    </tr><tr class="tbl_row_2" id="01_02-tbl_row_2" name="W003">
                                        <td>01.02</td>
                                        <td colspan="8" class="left_align wbs_master_list_td">Base Alm 17 SO</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="tbl_row_3">
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td class="cell_grp_brown">Test</td>
                                        <td colspan="7" class="left_align">Activity Description</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr><tr class="tbl_row_10" id="01_02-tbl_row_10">
                                        <td colspan="12" class="right_align">Subtotal For Base Alm 17 SO</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>$0</td>
                                    </tr><tr class="tbl_row_2" id="01_03-tbl_row_2" name="W004">
                                        <td>01.03</td>
                                        <td colspan="8" class="left_align wbs_master_list_td">Body Mixed &amp; //le </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>1634</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="tbl_row_3">
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td class="cell_grp_brown">Test</td>
                                        <td colspan="7" class="left_align">Activity Description</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>1634</td>
                                    </tr><tr class="tbl_row_4 no_wrap_class" id="H0111__W004__1000">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td class="cell_grp_brown">01.02.01</td>
                                            <td>1000</td>
                                            <td class="no_wrap_class">Map of Blue carousel</td>
                                            <td>CVENG</td>
                                            <td>NON O &amp; M</td>
                                            <td>140100</td>
                                            <td>Engineering</td>
                                            <td>789</td>
                                            <td><input size="1" value="1" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>HR</td>
                                            <td class="duration_cell">1 day</td>
                                            <td class="crew_cell"><select class="crew_dropdown"><option selected="">0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input value="1" size="1" class="unit_mhrs_input" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td><td><input class="total_cost_input" size="1" value="500" type="text"></td></tr><tr class="tbl_row_4 no_wrap_class" id="H0111__W004__1001">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td class="cell_grp_brown">01.02.02</td>
                                            <td>1001</td>
                                            <td class="no_wrap_class">Blue Tire Removal</td>
                                            <td>CVENG</td>
                                            <td>O &amp; M</td>
                                            <td>1301E</td>
                                            <td>Engineering</td>
                                            <td>789</td>
                                            <td><input size="1" value="1" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>HR</td>
                                            <td class="duration_cell">5 days</td>
                                            <td class="crew_cell"><select class="crew_dropdown"><option selected="">0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input value="1" size="1" class="unit_mhrs_input" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td><td><input class="total_cost_input" size="1" value="500" type="text"></td></tr><tr class="tbl_row_4 no_wrap_class" id="H0111__W004__1002">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td class="cell_grp_brown">01.02.03</td>
                                            <td>1002</td>
                                            <td class="no_wrap_class">Jet Blue Service A</td>
                                            <td>CVENG</td>
                                            <td>O &amp; M</td>
                                            <td>1301E</td>
                                            <td>Engineering</td>
                                            <td>789</td>
                                            <td><input size="1" value="1" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>HR</td>
                                            <td class="duration_cell">3 days</td>
                                            <td class="crew_cell"><select class="crew_dropdown"><option selected="">0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input value="1" size="1" class="unit_mhrs_input" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td><td><input class="total_cost_input" size="1" value="500" type="text"></td></tr><tr class="tbl_row_4 no_wrap_class" id="H0111__W004__1003">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td class="cell_grp_brown">01.02.04</td>
                                            <td>1003</td>
                                            <td class="no_wrap_class">Air Pressure Blue Pin</td>
                                            <td>TRENG</td>
                                            <td>Indirect</td>
                                            <td>180100</td>
                                            <td>Engineering</td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td><input size="1" value="1" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>HR</td>
                                            <td class="duration_cell">4 days</td>
                                            <td class="crew_cell"><select class="crew_dropdown"><option selected="">0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input value="1" size="1" class="unit_mhrs_input" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td><td><input class="total_cost_input" size="1" value="12" type="text"></td></tr><tr class="tbl_row_4 no_wrap_class" id="H0111__W004__1004">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td class="cell_grp_brown">01.02.05</td>
                                            <td>1004</td>
                                            <td class="no_wrap_class">Blue Tax Appraisal For Marty James</td>
                                            <td>TRENG</td>
                                            <td>O &amp; M</td>
                                            <td>1301E</td>
                                            <td>Engineering</td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td><input size="1" value="1" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>HR</td>
                                            <td class="duration_cell">5 days</td>
                                            <td class="crew_cell"><select class="crew_dropdown"><option selected="">0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input value="1" size="1" class="unit_mhrs_input" type="text"></td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>1</td><td><input class="total_cost_input" size="1" value="122" type="text"></td></tr><tr class="tbl_row_10" id="01_03-tbl_row_10">
                                        <td colspan="12" class="right_align">Subtotal For Body Mixed &amp; //le </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>$1634</td>
                                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>                
        </div>
```

Below is the css code for this :

```
.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1, .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_5_right{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_5_right,.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_2,.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_2, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1 td:nth-child(odd){
    font-size: 13px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1 input[type="text"]{
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 110px;
}
.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1 input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_3, .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_3,.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_2,.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_2, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_2 table, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_3 table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1 td, .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1 th, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4 td, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4 th, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4 td, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4 th{
    border: none !important;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_3 label,.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_5_left .form-group label,.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_2 label,.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_2 label{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_5_left li label{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_4 ul li{
    border-left: 1px solid black; 
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_4 ul li:first-child{
    border: none; 
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_4 ul li:first-child input{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_3_4_hr,.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_2_3_hr{
    border: 4px solid #b4b40f;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_5_right_2, .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_7_col_1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_7_col_1{
    padding: 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_6{
    margin:10px;
}
.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_6 button, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_3_footer_button_row button{
    border: 1px solid #351f72;
    color: #351f72;
    background-color: #e9b947;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_6, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_3_footer_button_row{
    text-align: center;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_3_footer_button_row{
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.padding_less{
    padding: unset;
}

.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_2 span{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e3960a;
}

.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_3, .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_3{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_3 table th{
    padding: unset;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.estimatigPortfolio_top_row li{
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_3{
    border: 3px solid #ccc1c1;
}

.glyphicon-one-fine-empty-dot::before{
    content: "\25cf";
}

.main_row{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;

}

.glyphicon-one-fine-empty-dot{
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.glyphicon_dot_1{
    color: #daa50f;
}

.glyphicon_dot_2{
    color: #8c7dda;
}

.glyphicon_dot_3{
    color: #ec3434;
}

.sub_row .glyphicon-plus{
    font-size: 12 !important;
    margin-right: 12px !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
}

.sub_row{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 3px 6%
}

.sub_row div:first-child{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: -3%;
    color: #0ca6d8;
}

.sub_row .sub_row_right_div{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin-right: 15px; 
}

.sub_row .sub_row_right_div span:first-child{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #782828 !important;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_3_col_1, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_3_col_1{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 350px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_3_col_1 table th{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_3_col_1 td{
    font-size: 13px;
}


.eselection_form{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_4 .list-inline{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding: 15px 0px !important;
}


.tbl_row_head, .tbl_row_1, .tbl_row_10{
    background-color: #3399CC;
}
.tbl_row_1{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tbl_row_head th{
    white-space: pre;
}

.tbl_row_head th{
    font-weight: normal;
}

.ips_template_table_col .table-responsive{
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.tbl_row_10{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tbl_row_2{
    background-color: #E6EDE2;
}

.tbl_row_3, .tbl_row_9{
    background-color: #CCDD90;
}

.tbl_row_4, .tbl_row_5, .tbl_row_6, .tbl_row_7, .tbl_row_8, .tbl_row_9{
    background-color: #f3f2c1;
}

.tbl_style tr:not(.tbl_row_1):not(.tbl_row_2):not(.tbl_row_10) td:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #EEDDDC;
}

.tbl_style tr:not(.tbl_row_1):not(.tbl_row_10) td:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #E6EDE2 !important;;
}

.tbl_style > tbody > tr > td, .tbl_style > tbody > tr > th, .tbl_style > tfoot > tr > td, .tbl_style > tfoot > tr > th, .tbl_style > thead > tr > td, .tbl_style > thead > tr > th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.ips_template_table_col{
    background-color: #fcfcf1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_1 table, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_2 table{
    font-size: 16px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_1 select, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_2 select{
    width:90%;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_2 table:not(a), .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_3 table input[type="text"]{
    font-size: 13px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_2 tr:first-child input, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_3 tr:first-child input{
    width:90%;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_2 tr:last-child input, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_3 tr:last-child input{
    width:95%;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_2 table a, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_3 table a{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_2 table .vertical_align, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_3 .vertical_align{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_3 table{
    font-size: 12px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_heading_div, .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_heading_div, .overview_master_list_estimate_modal_heading_div{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0px;   
}

.estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_heading_div span, .overview_master_list_estimate_modal_heading_div span{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 10%;
}

.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_heading_div span{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 2%;
}

.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_4 table{
    font-size: 15px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_col_4 thead, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_col_3 thead{
    border-top: 5px solid #64afe7;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #64afe7;
}

#split_testing_commissioning_modal .modal-dialog, #ichrs_non_incremental_cost_modal .modal-dialog, #overview_master_list_estimate_modal .modal-dialog{
    width: 85% !important;
}

.modal_table_scroll{
    max-height: 40%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.etemplate_btn_div{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.etemplate_btn_div button{
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1 table{
    margin-bottom: unset;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_0_tbl_pid, .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_0_tbl_pin{
    margin-left: 13%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px){
    .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_0_tbl_pj_name{
        margin-left: 3%;
    }

    .estimatigPortfolioSplit_row_4_heading_div span, .overview_master_list_estimate_modal_heading_div span, .estimatigPortfolioIchrs_row_4_heading_div span{
        display: block;
        white-space: normal;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
    .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_0_tbl_pj_name input[type="text"]{
        width: 100%;
    }    
    .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_0_tbl_pj_name{
        margin-left: -5%;
    }
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_3{
    padding: 1% 0px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_2  select, .estimatigPortfolioOverview_row_1_div_3 select{
    width: 70px;
}

#header_div_checkbox{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#header_div{
    display: none;
}

.master_list_est_row_1_col_1 .table-responsive{
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#master_excel_file{
    display: none;
}

.master_list_est_row_1_col_2{
    text-align: center;
}

.left_align, .tbl_row_4 td{
    text-align: left;
}

#master_list_modal_on_template .modal-dialog{
    width: 85%;
}

.right_align{
    text-align: right;
}

.no_wrap_class{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.tbl_row_2 td:nth-child(2){
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.tbl_row_3 td:nth-child(2), .tbl_row_4 td:nth-child(2){
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a piece of code you have tried to achieve it? Because it really makes the life easy for the people trying to find a solution.

Comment: I think your `items` option is set incorrectly. Please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Twisty . It's difficult to extract minimal working code as it contains many other things as well and if provide complete code it will be a very big chunk.As far items are concerned, I have provided the class (.tbl_row_4) which is applied to all the rows which have yellow backround.

Comment: Need to see the html for the tables at least.

Comment: @Twisty , modified the question and updated the code.

Comment: @Abhi I do not see jQuery or jQuery UI libraries added to your example code. I assume you are using them. Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/gz28vdbx/

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing, I could see no major issues with the code. I did find a few HTML Syntax issues that you should work to correct. Like:

```
<tr class="tbl_row_head" "="">
```

This will cause issues.

My testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/gz28vdbx/1/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#etemplate_table_id").sortable({ /*etemplate_table_id - table id*/
    items: "* > .tbl_row_4",
    /*tbl_row_4 - class of rows in yellow color*/
    cursor: "move"
  });
});
```

I was able to sort just the rows that were `.tbl_row_4` without issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my code is also working same as given in the fiddle.
But my problem is that the row of one section should not allowed to drop in the other section.
For example, yellow rows under  head and trauma should not be allowed to in between the rowas under body mixed.

Thanks for highlighting this (<tr class="tbl_row_head" "="">) , but it arises due to copy pastea nd editing.Its not issue source code is correct.

Comment: Can you sort out this issue   ?

Comment: @Abhi haven't had a moment to review the issue.